# Как в С++ CLI присвоить несколько событий для кнопки

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Как в `С++` присвоять несколько событий для кнопки например: нажал - она увеличилась, нажал ещё раз - уменьшилась.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно одного события, которое будет иметь проверку

```
if(this->button->Width == BUTTON_MAX_WIDTH){
  this->button->Size = System::Drawing::Size(BUTTON_MIN_WIDTH, BUTTON_MIN_HEIGHT);
} else{
  this->button->Size = System::Drawing::Size(BUTTON_MAX_WIDTH, BUTTON_MAX_HEIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все-таки сильно хочется сделать это через несколько событий, объявите в классе формы два события:

```
private: System::EventHandler ^FirstClick = gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click1);
private: System::EventHandler ^SecondClick = gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click2);
```

Затем, например, в конструкторе добавьте методу `button1->Click` любое из этих событий:

```
this->button1->Click += FirstClick;
```

Затем напишите реализацию этих функций, каждая из которых после основного функционала будет в методе `button1->Click` убирать себя и добавлять другую функцию:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    /* КНОПКА УВЕЛИЧИЛАСЬ */
    this->button1->Click -= this->FirstClick;
    this->button1->Click += this->SecondClick;
}

private: System::Void button1_Click2(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    /* КНОПКА УМЕНЬШИЛАСЬ */
    this->button1->Click -= this->SecondClick;
    this->button1->Click += this->FirstClick;
}
```